# What's the proper HTTP error code to use when request is missing origin header?

Tags: http

I am designing an API and a requirement to access some endpoints is the [Origin header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) must be set in the request. I am rejecting requests that either (a) are missing the header altogether or (b) are sending requests from an origin that is not in a specified allowlist.

When I reject requests that do not meet these criteria, what is the correct HTTP error code to use? I initially thought [401](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) or [403](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403), but there's not any true authentication/authorization issue in these cases. [400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) feels too generic. Is there a code more specific to this scenario?

Comment: `400` and `403` are probably both fine, `401` is definitely not. When in doubt about what `4xx` status to send, `400` is usually fine. It's mostly useful to send more specific HTTP errors if the client can do something useful with that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 400 may feel "too generic" but I think it's for this exact scenario where you are rejecting incomplete or otherwise bad requests.